# How to have Meteor Cordova app allow access to a domain

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I just did a meteor update and now have versions:
Meteor 1.0.4
Cordova 4.2.0

I also recently used mup deploy to move my server to digital ocean.

What I've found now is that while the desktop and mobile websites work fine, in the Android mobile app, the images no longer load. These images are public URLs.

I read here:
https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/17/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions

that Meteor Cordova apps no longer allow access to all domains by default. We need to whitelist allowed domains using App.accessRule method in mobile-config.js.

So I tried to set up mobile-config.js like so:

```
App.accessRule(
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/*",
    {
        launchExternal: true
    }
);
```

But the images that come from that domain still do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. launchExternal needs to be set to false to be handled internally (i.e. displayed on screen) by the Meteor app itself.