# Unauthorized Error when Loading Images on iPhone in Meteor/Cordova App

Tags: ios, image, cordova, meteor

What is the correct way to load image urls from a meteor/cordova iphone app?

Currently, I set the img src as: http://content.shoprite.com/legacy/productimagesroot/DJ/7/1077397.jpg

Here's the error I get in the console via Safari:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) (1077397.jpg, line 0)

This issue does not exist when testing in browser (safari/chrome) on both desktop and mobile, only in the iOS app, which makes me think it must be a Cordova issue. All images in my public folder still display just fine.

The two reasons I think this may be occurring are:

1) The domains from which the images are being downloaded need to be approved via accessRule as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156811/how-to-have-meteor-cordova-app-allow-access-to-a-domain).

2) The images are downloaded locally to the phone and then unable to be accessed as in [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3799).

For context, I was able to do this successfully in previous builds of my meteor app. After updating to Meteor 1.2 is when I noticed this problem AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the first reason that I had mentioned - I needed to whitelist public urls.

Solved by adding the following to my mobile-config.js file:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```